# SQL Server agent error on a the mirror database

Tags: sql-server, clustering, sql-server-agent, mirroring

I configured mirroring on one of my databases. The database is in a SQL Server cluster.

The mirroring is working great, but all the jobs that set to run fail.

The error is:

> Date      9/10/2015 8:00:00 AM Log        SQL Server Agent (Current - 9/9/2015
>   8:00:00 AM)
>
> Message [165] ODBC Error: 0, Connecting to a mirrored SQL Server
>   instance using the MultiSubnetFailover connection option is not
>   supported. [SQLSTATE IMH01]

What to do? Why is it happening?

Comment: Are you doing cross database transactions - using DTC ? `Cross-database transactions and distributed transactions are not supported by AlwaysOn Availability Groups or by database mirroring.` [Refer BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366279(v=sql.120).aspx)

Comment: I don't have any Availability group. What have is a clustering . And my database is use to a mirror and log shipping together . As I wrote in my question .

Comment: You are using mirroring .. correct ? DId you read the BOL reference link ? Are you using any cross database or distributed transactions ? From the error message it appears the case